# checking if value is empty

Tags: php, string, wordpress, is-empty

I'm trying to patch up some code that outputs a date range in our wp functions file. Here is the code that was built:

```
function date_flip() {
    global $custom_metabox; //needed    
    $start_date = $custom_metabox->get_the_value('start_date');
    $end_date   = $custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date');
    //start day
    $s_day   = substr($start_date,8,2);
    $s_month = substr($start_date,5,2);
    $s_year  = substr($start_date,0,4);
    //end day
    $e_day   = substr($end_date,8,2);
    $e_month = substr($end_date,5,2);
    $e_year  = substr($end_date,0,4);
    //mash up
    $start_date = $s_day . "." . $s_month . "." . $s_year;
    $end_date   = $e_day . "." . $e_month . "." . $e_year;
    //spew out
    echo $start_date . '&thinsp;–&thinsp;' . $end_date;
}
```

The issue I have is that, sometimes we don't put in an end_date in our posts, so this code outputs a blank set of numbers…
for example `9.9.2015–..`

I was trying to narrow it down by not implementing the $end_date using a check if empty value but it ends up just hanging up my site.

I replaced the last echo with this:

```
function date_flip() {
    global $custom_metabox; //needed    
    $start_date = $custom_metabox->get_the_value('start_date');
    $end_date   = $custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date');
    //start day
    $s_day   = substr($start_date,8,2);
    $s_month = substr($start_date,5,2);
    $s_year  = substr($start_date,0,4);
    //end day
    $e_day   = substr($end_date,8,2);
    $e_month = substr($end_date,5,2);
    $e_year  = substr($end_date,0,4);
    //mash up
    $start_date = $s_day . "." . $s_month . "." . $s_year;
    $end_date   = $e_day . "." . $e_month . "." . $e_year;
    //spew out
    echo $start_date;
    if ( !empty( $custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date') ) ) {
        echo '&thinsp;–&thinsp;' . $end_date;
    } else {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
```

any clue why this might hang up the entire site?

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `)` -

```
if ( !empty( $custom_metabox->get_the_value( 'end_date' ) ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your code with below. Missing a parenthese

```
global $custom_metabox;
echo $start_date;
if ( !empty( $custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date') ) ) {
    echo '&thinsp;–&thinsp;' . $end_date;
} else {
    //DO NOTHING
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was clumsy thanks for catching that. Oddly however, it still seems to hang up the functions code entirely and returns a `failed to load resource`

Comment: @antonanton Have you write this line `global $custom_metabox;` before check empty?

Comment: yes the only line that has changed is the last one, the rest of the function looks as it is in the first example

Comment: @antonanton No i think you getting me wrong, i updated my answer check it.

Comment: The `global $custom_metabox;` is referenced in the first line, updated my answer so you can see how the code was re-written

Comment: @antonanton Have you tried `isset()` or by check the value like `!=""` (not equal to blank)?

Comment: @antonanton And in the updated code of your question again you miss the `)` in if. :)

Comment: Ah, yea that was another silly mistake. Reflected the question better to how its actually in my code. I tried isset, and that also does not work. I also tried replacing `$custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date')` simply with `$end_date` and the site works, but it does not output no data if there is no date…

Comment: @antonanton Then may be there is one issue only i think what are you trying to fatch is wrong or something mashing or missing. First try to echo the value `$custom_metabox->get_the_value('end_date')` and put `die;` after it and check have you seen the output? And one more thing open wp-config.php and replace `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. After doing above changes you can see all the errors and notices.